# Resolvers in GraphQL do not seem to get context

Tags: graphql, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I am using resolvers inside `query_type`:

```
module Types
  class QueryType < Types::BaseObject
...
    field :gather_things,
          resolver: Resolvers::GatherThings,
          null: true do
      argument :scope, String, required: false
      argument :scope_id, ID, required: false
...
```

And in my `resolvers` folder there is a `base` file:

```
module Resolvers
  class Base < GraphQL::Schema::Resolver
    def current_user_id
      @current_user_id ||= context[:current_user].id
    end
  end
end
```

However, when I try to use `current_user_id` inside the resolver code, it breaks:

```
module Resolvers
  class GatherThings < Resolvers::Base
...
    def things_resolver(scope, scope_id)
      if scope.nil?
        Thing.from_user(current_user_id)
...
      end
    end
...
```

Saying : `"undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass"`

Any clue?

Comment: I also tried to define `current_user_id` inside the resolver, but still same error.

Comment: Version of `graphql-ruby` is 2.0.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later found out that something was nullifying my session upstream.
This was due to the use of JWTs for session management and mixing them with cookies for OmniAuth.
I have to work out on a solution for using both depending on the intended use.